# PHP: include() bug, or user error? (Passed filename in IF statement)

Tags: php, string, if-statement, include

Alright so I've already created a PHP bug about this but it was marked as bogus, but I can't help but to believe they didn't read it carefully...

[Link to Bug #54042](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=54042)

The error is caused by using an `include()` statement in an `IF` statement, making the statement believe it's been passed an empty string.

Reviewing the bug will explain everything, including a test script.

Is it a bug, or am I missing something "feature"-wise? This is weird seeing as how assigning the output of `include` to a variable and *then* testing that value works just fine (which would be the workaround).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) says:

> Because `include()` is a special language construct, parentheses are not needed around its argument. Take care when comparing return value.
>
> ```
> <?php
> // won't work, evaluated as include(('vars.php') == 'OK'), i.e. include('')
> if (include('vars.php') == 'OK') {
>     echo 'OK';
> }
>
> // works
> if ((include 'vars.php') == 'OK') {
>     echo 'OK';
> }
> ?>
> ```

So this behaviour is already known and not considered as a bug. You even have an explanation *why* it works this way:

`include` does not need parenthesis, so PHP does not really whether you want to do:

```
include('vars.php')
```

or

```
include(('vars.php') == 'OK')
```

It seems that it is implemented to interpet it as the latter (something like the longest possible match).

Same goes for

```
$v = include('foo') . 'bar';
```

which PHP interprets as

```
$v = include(('foo') . 'bar');
```

and tries to load `foobar`.

But the solution is also given: Wrap the whole include statement into parenthesis, then there is only one way how PHP can interpret the call:

```
$v = (include ('foo')) . 'bar';
```

---

(Maybe) off topic: You will find similar "issues" in other parts of PHP. Take variable variables:

```
$obj->$foo['bar'];
```

PHP does not know whether you want to access the `bar` element of the array `$foo` and use this value as property name:

```
$obj->{$foo['bar']};
```

or if you want to access the `bar` element of `$obj->$foo`:

```
{$obj->$foo}['bar'];
```

---

In all these cases, there is a *default behaviour* of the parser. The developers decided for one possibility because they had to. It might not be what you expect, but if you know it, you can deal with it.

This behaviour cannot simply be changed as it might break code that relies on this behaviour.

Comment: I don't know, I was able to get it to work with the parentheses or without, as long as I omitted the comparison. I get a big ugly warning if I don't have a correct path.

Comment: @Jared Farrish: Yes, as written *parentheses are not needed*, that is why it can act strangely if you have further operators in the line. E.g. `include('foo') . "bar"` tries to include `foobar`, not concatenate the return value with `bar`.

Comment: @Felix - I'm just thinking, you could probably add some more examples of when it does/doesn't work. Does that mean you could have the file path/name be a variable and check for it matching the variable plus the parentheticals?

Comment: @Jared Farrish: Sorry, it's late here, I should go to sleep ;)

Comment: @Felix - No worries, I think you did a good job. The It it is no more, and overall, I think your answer contributes to a better understanding. Certainly, one of the more interesting "bug"-like behaviors I've seen. You provide an alternative, better answer, so I gave you a vote. And I think the OP should mark this an answer.

Comment: @Felix - Now, you should probably hit the sack. :)

Comment: @Jared Farrish: Hehe ok :D Enjoy your day ;)

Comment: @Felix - That'll be tomorrow, btw. I live in Texas; we aren't too far ahead from Germany (my assumption).

Comment: AHA, thank you. One of those little language construct glitches that I wasn't thinking of. Thanks Felix!